How can one persist an AttributedString within the SwiftData framework?
The problem of how to persist AttributedString data within the SwiftData framework isn't, as far as I can tell, specifically addressed anywhere. And since (custom) AttributedStrings address several critical functions for me, I'm hoping someone here has the solution. Apple's documentation seems to suggest that conformance to the Codable protocol is basically all that's needed. Yet although AttributedStrings are themselves Codable, simply marking a class that contains one with the @Model macro makes that class not Codable.
Paul Hudson explains How to make SwiftData models conform to Codable, the gist being that you need to manually add conformance using CodingKeys, init(from:), and encode(to:). But when I tried that (admittedly without really knowing what I was doing), it didn't work.
In the following code, which runs, changing the four places where String is mentioned, to AttributedString causes the program to crash and produce a rather long, complicated error message.
What's wrong? And more importantly, what can one do to overcome this problem?
import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

@main
struct SwiftDataTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(for: Item.self)
    }
}

import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    @Query private var arrayOfItems: [Item]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Add Item") {
                addItem()
            }
            List {
                ForEach(arrayOfItems) { item in
                    Text(item.text)
                }
                .onDelete { indexes in
                    for index in indexes {
                        deleteItem(arrayOfItems[index])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func addItem() {
        let item = Item(text: String("Plain Text"))
        context.insert(item)
    }
    
    func deleteItem(_ item: Item) {
        context.delete(item)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
        .modelContainer(for: Item.self)
}

@Model
class Item: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey { case text }

    var text: String
    
    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        text = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .text)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(text, forKey: .text)
    }
}


There must be some misunderstanding here, you don't need to explicitly make your model conform to Codable because it has a a Codable property. And where is the AttributedString in all this?

Thanks for the reply, Joakim. As I mentioned in the text above, if you replace the references to String with AttributedString, the code crashes. I wrote the code with just String to demonstrate that it runs before this change. As for the explicit code to make it conform to Codable, it does seem to be required when I add an @Transient AttributedString. Otherwise, just having AttributedString in the class crashes the program.

I still see no reason why Item needs to conform to Codable. I believe the issue is with AttributedString itself .

Well, regardless of whether or not it explicitly needs to conform to Codable, it doesn't work; and that's a problem that needs solving.

You could try looking into @Attribute(.transformable(by: ...)) var text: AttributedString
and create the appropriate ValueTransformer, see also: SO similar
